# Why does there need to be more than one type of covering sieve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Let $C$ be a category. If $X$ is an object of $C$, then write $\underline{X} = \text{Hom}(-, X): C^{\text{op}}\to \text{Sets}$ for the corresponding functor.

Suppose that a "cover" of $X$ is a subfunctor $i: \mathcal{U}\to \underline{X}$ such that, for every object $Y$ of $C$, the function
\begin{equation}
i^\ast: \text{Hom}(\underline{X}, \underline{Y})\to \text{Hom}(\mathcal{U}, \underline{Y}).
\end{equation}
is a bijection. To me this definition seems to perfectly capture the notion of a cover: each morphism $\mathcal{U}\to \underline{Y}$ uniquely defines a morphism $X\to Y$. What more (or less) could you ask of a cover?

I have never seen this definition stated or discussed anywhere. I am guessing this notion of cover is at least somewhat related to a covering sieve for the canonical topology (but I'm not sure how to prove it), because it seems that the above definition is the minimal requirement for every representable functor to be a sheaf.

Now the category of schemes, for example, has many different types of covering sieves, leading to many different Grothendieck topologies. Why is my above notion of cover not sufficient for all purposes? What is a specific example of something you can do with insert-grothendieck-topology-here that you wouldn't be able to do with my above definition of cover?

Comment: One issue I can see with your notion of cover (I hope I didn’t misunderstand you) is that you actively impose a topology on the category, only in terms of this category. But, for instance, it’s an important part of the properties of étale cohomology to show that $H^1_{ét}(\mathcal{O}^{\times}) \rightarrow H^1_{Zar}(\mathcal{O}^{\times})$ is an isomorphism for eg the category of étale schemes over a scheme $X$ with respectively the Zariski and the étale coverings. So you need *two* different topologies on the same category for this. Also, note how étale/fppf coverings are defined geometrically.

Comment: It is difficult to explicitly characterise the class of sieves satisfying this condition, and it is not stable under pullback.

Comment: By "the corresponding functor" you mean the image under the Yoneda embedding I assume? So $\underline{X} = \operatorname{Hom}(-, X)$? It might be good to note that in your question.

Comment: @Zhen Lin do you have an example of a category where this condition is not stable under pullbacks? I worked out the details for the case $C = \text{Op}(X)$, the category of open subsets of a topological space, and I found that my definition of cover reproduces the standard notion of covering sieve. So in this classical case (I think) everything works out nicely.

Comment: @Mark Kamsma thanks fixed.

Comment: Take any category where "epimorphic sieve" and "universally epimorphic sieve" are distinct notions. For example, any category with pullbacks in which the class of regular epimorphisms is not closed under pullbacks.

Comment: @Zhen Lin what does it mean for a sieve to be epimorphic? My naive guess is that the inclusion map $\mathcal{U}\to \underline{X}$ is an epimorphism in the category of presheaves, but that doesn't make sense. Since the inclusion is automatically object-wise injective, if it is an epimorphism (in the category of presheaves) then it would be object-wise surjective as well and hence an isomorphism. But certainly an epimorphic sieve is not always an isomorphism.

Comment: The definition of "cover" in your post is precisely the definition of epimorphic sieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and answers. Do you know of any reference book or paper that defines epimorphic sieve? And what exactly does "epimorphic sieve" have to do with an actual epimorphism in some category?

Comment: A morphism is a _strict_ epimorphism if and only if it generates an epimorphic sieve in the sense above. Actually I think some people say _strict_-epimorphic sieve or _effective_-epimorphic sieve instead for this notion. It's not studied much, except in relation to _universally_ epimorphic sieves, which are the covering sieves in the canonical topology.